# How can tumah pass through a cupboard?

Tags: commentaries, mishna, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity

[Ohalot 4:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Oholot.4?lang=bi) says that where there is a source of tumah beneath a cupboard, everything in the house is tamei.

ArtScroll adds that the things in the *cupboard* remain tahor: “the tumah penetrates into the cupboard only to the extent of passing through it to go beyond it (into the house) but not to the extent of making anything in the cupboard tamei”.

It cites three sources: Rash, Chazon Ish 3:3, and Mikdash David Kuntres Tohorot 1:3 ד״ה הנה זה. I’ve found the relevant passage of Mikdash David and pasted it below. Rash is available [here](https://www.sefaria.org/Rash_MiShantz_on_Mishnah_Oholot.4.1.1?lang=bi) and Chazon Ish [here](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14338&st=&pgnum=129&hilite=). Only issue is… I can’t follow the argument! Can anyone help me understand these sources and how it is that tumah can pass through a cupboard while leaving the contents tahor?

> מקדש דוד קונטרס מעניני טהרות סימן א ——— הנה זה דכלים המוקפין צ"פ דמצילין
> רק ע"מ שבתוכן ולא ע"מ שחוצה להן נראה דאין זה רק שאין חוצצין דחשבינן
> כאילו אינן רק דלענין מה שחוצה להם ג"כ מביאין דלענין זה הטומאה נכנסת
> לתוכן וראיה לזה ממ"ש הר"ש ז"ל פ"ד גבי מגדל היה עומד בתוך הבית כלים
> שבינו ובין הארץ שבינו לבין הקורות אם אין בהם פ"ט טהורין טומאה שם הבית
> טמא וכתב הר"ש ז"ל משום דטומאה בוקעת לתוך המגדל ויוצאת מפתחה להבית ע"ש.
> וקשה איך נכנסת הטומאה לתוכה הא מיירי במגדל הבא במדה והוי ג"כ כמו מוקפת
> צ"פ כמ"ש הר"ש ז"ל שם א"כ אף טומאה רצוצה אין נכנסת לתוכה ומ"ש מכוורת
> וטומאה רצוצה תחתיה דכל מה שבתוכה טהור כמ"ש הר"ש ז"ל בפ"ט וע"כ כיון
> דהכא מיירי לטמא את הבית שהוא חוצה לה וע"מ שחוצה לה אינה מצלת כמו התם
> בכוורת וכיון שכתב הר"ש ז"ל דהטומאה בוקעת למגדל ויוצאת מפתחה להבית מוכח
> דלענין מה שחוצה לה הטומאה נכנסת לתוכה ויוצאת מפתחה שהוא מן הצד לבית
> דמביאה את הטומאה לבית כמו שאר אהל:

Comment: Chazon Ish seems to conclude with a tzarich iyun.

Comment: @N.T. Yup, though that doesn't help me understand what he said right before.

Comment: Will do a proper write-up, but basically the idea is that the protection the cupboard offers is not that of a regular ohel, but a special halacha for kelim (ie the cupboard here) that even though they protect what's in them under certain cases, they still bring tumah (as an ohel) w.r. to what's outside of them. and cannot block tumah (see eg beginning of perek 6 and 9). The chiddush here is that it applies even within the kli itself (and this extra bit seems to be contradicted by perek 9, so tz"i)

Comment: @AKA Thanks, will really look forward to reading more!

Comment: @AKA ❓ Would love to read your analysis of this!

Comment: @Zarka haven't forgotten, just juggling family/work etc :)

Comment: @Zarka on the way bln